# Printing JUST values from hashmap when Value is an object

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I am trying to print values from a hashmap without printing the accosiated key. Here is what I have at the minute, its the "printValues" method that isn't working correctly

```
private Map<String, Object> customers;

   public MakeMap()
   {
      newHash = new HashMap<>();          
   }

   public void addObject(String reg, String name, String address, int age)
   {
          newHash.put(reg,new HashObject( name, address, age));
   }

   public void printValues()
   {
       Set<Entry<String,Object>> hashSet=newHash.entrySet();
        for(Entry entry:hashSet ) {
            System.out.println(entry.toString());
        } 

}
```

When I run the following: (i have a toString method in a seperate class)

```
aClass.addCustomer("123ABC","John Doe", "5 Code Street", 22);
aClass.printCustomers();
```

I get this returned:

```
123ABC=John Doe 5 Code Street age: 22
```

Whereas I would like the following to print:

```
John Doe 5 Code Street age: 22
```

Comment: Use `keySet()` instead of `entrySet()`

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGHHHHH... Thank you!

Comment: Actually, when I do that it refuses to compile, due to incompatable types. Any ideas, do I need to import another function?

Comment: @Obviously `keySet` returns a `Set<String>`, not a `Set<Entry<String,Object>>` so you have to make some changes in your code.

Comment: thanks, now I feel a little bit silly! thank you!